# Linkdln API Error "status":"CLIENT_ERROR"

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I am getting client error when I tried to post a video with linkdln API. I read docs and everything but it didn't get solved.

```
def get_video_upload_url(token, person_id,):
        headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                   'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
                   'LinkedIn-Version': '202306',
                   'x-li-format': 'json',
                   }

    #data here
    data = {
        "registerUploadRequest": {
            "owner": f"urn:li:person:{person_id}",
            "recipes": [
                "urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:feedshare-video"
            ],
            "serviceRelationships": [
                {
                    "identifier": "urn:li:userGeneratedContent",
                    "relationshipType": "OWNER"
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    response = requests.post('https://api.linkedin.com/rest/assets?action=registerUpload', json=data, headers=headers)
    byte_content = response.content.decode().replace("'", '"')
    content = json.loads(byte_content)
    upload_url_ = content["value"]["uploadMechanism"]["com.linkedin.digitalmedia.uploading.MediaUploadHttpRequest"][
        "uploadUrl"]
    asset_ = content["value"]["asset"]
    return upload_url_, asset_




def video_upload(file_path, url):
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'LinkedIn-Version': '202306',
        'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0'}

    # response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, data={'file': open(file_path, 'rb')})
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, files={'file': file})

    if response.status_code == 201:
        print('upload video success')
        return response.content
    else:
        print('upload video fail', response.text)
```

```
def check_video_is_ready(token, asset_id):
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
               'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
               'LinkedIn-Version': '202306',
               'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0'}
    response = requests.get(url=CHECK_VIDEO_URL + asset_id[25:], headers=headers)
    print(response)
    print(response.text)

upload_url, asset = get_video_upload_url(token=ACCESS_TOKEN,
                                         person_id='EI_yar03i3')  # person_id=login(token=ACCESS_TOKEN))


video_upload(file_path="/Users/selman/PycharmProjects/linkdln/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4", url=upload_url)


print(check_video_is_ready(token=ACCESS_TOKEN, asset_id=asset))
print(check_video_is_ready(token=ACCESS_TOKEN, asset_id=asset))
print(check_video_is_ready(token=ACCESS_TOKEN, asset_id=asset))

Output
upload video success
<Response [200]>
{"recipes":[{"recipe":"urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:feedshare-video","status":"CLIENT_ERROR"}]
```

My video file format is mp4 and size is 2mb. Why output is

> {"recipes":[{"recipe":"urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:feedshare-video","status":"CLIENT_ERROR"}]

I read docs and docs: CLIENT_ERROR for file size error and file format error.
But my format and size is okay.